# Calling a method from one class in another.

Tags: c#, asp.net, access-modifiers

I have a parent page that has a RadTabStrip on it. On the TabClick event I want to call a function from one of the tabs(child page). On the child page I will be setting a control to visible=false; I will let the child page handle the control handling I just need to call it in my parent page because both tabs are being rendered at once so when I switch from tab to tab it doesn't see that its on a page load so it wont try to make the panel visible=false;

This is the Parent Page.

```
public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // call controls_confgMangrEvntNotif_confgMngrTab1.Test();
}
```

This is the child page and the meth I wish to call.

```
public partial class controls_confgMangrEvntNotif_confgMngrTab1 : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public static void Test()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("test");
    }
```

I believe my current problem is do to access modifiers. If I do the name of the class . it will give me a hashtable I made public static but no other functions or variables.

Comment: So what is the issue you're facing right now?

Comment: You need an instance (`new` it up) to access instance members. Only static members can be accessed without an instance.

Comment: @PoweredByOrange: The problem I am facing is that I can't call the function test in that parent page.

Comment: @NitroFrost Do you get any compile errors?

Comment: @retailcoder: What do you mean by that. something name = new controls_confgMangrEvntNotif_confgMngrTab1.test() ?

Comment: @PoweredByOrange O__O now its showing up and letting me set it. I will have to work on this a bit more. I don't know what happened. Maybe it was because I restarted VS. That is so weird.

Comment: Ended up that it worked just that it caused really bad performance issues. Have to rethink my strategy.